# Integrate swagger with Hybris 6.2

Tags: java, swagger-2.0, sap-commerce-cloud, swagger-codegen

I am working on hybris 6.2 version. I want to integrate swagger with hybris. Does this version supports swagger? If it does what steps i need to follow?

Answer (score 1):

**I am working on hybris 6.2 version. I want to integrate swagger with hybris. Does this version supports swagger?**

Yes, it does.

**If it does what steps i need to follow?**

Please check https://answers.sap.com/questions/12759475/view.html

Another useful thread is https://answers.sap.com/questions/12767953/view.html

Comment: In StackOverflow, it is recommended to post the full answers or reference to existing SO questions / answers, not just a link to external sites, because it's possible that the resource in external sites could get deleted.

Comment: Thanks Arvind for reply.